# What is the common idea of perl modules with Tie:: namespace?

Tags: perl, naming, tie

There are a lot of modules with `Tie::`namespace on CPAN - [Tie::Hash](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/lib/Tie/Hash.pm), [Tie::Sub](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::Sub), [Tie::Cache](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::Cache), [Tie::DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::DBI), etc. What is common among them ?

I checked [perltie](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perltie.pod) but 'm not sure that I understood the concept clear. Could someone explain it?

Comment: It is more or less to bind a perl structure in memory directly to a file. So when your script/application closes and starts again it can excess the prior values.

Comment: @smartmeta That's only a small subset of what the `tie` interface can do. One of the oldest, certainly, but the `tie` interface is a general-purpose interface that allows tying most kinds of Perl variables to any logic one wants.

Answer (score 9):

The modules in the Tie:: namespace fall into two categories:

- Those that implement a class to which a variable can be tied (e.g. [Tie::DBI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tie::DBI)), and
- Those that assist the user in building such classes (e.g. [Tie::Hash](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tie::Hash)).

[`tie`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tie.html) allows an object to take on the interface of a variable. When you read from a tied variable, you are actually calling a method to retrieve information. When you write to a tied variable, you are actually calling a method to with the information.

For example, let's look at a hash tied to Tie::DBI.

- When you list the keys of the hash, a method is called which obtains the primary key of each row of a database table instead.
- When you fetch the value of an element of the hash, a method is called which gets the specified row of a database table instead.
- When you create/set the value of an element of the hash, a method is called which creates/set the fields of the specified row of a database table instead.

Answer (score 3):

It only covers tying hashes, but my [article on perl.com from 2001](https://www.perl.com/pub/2001/09/04/tiedhash.html/) might answer a few questions.